# Relation between Lie Algebra and Inner Product ? Motivation of the definition of lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I notice that the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Definitions) of a Lie Algebra has a very similar structure of the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition)
is there some kind of relation between those 2 definitions, I doubt it because those are both abstract things, and it wouldn't make sense to have 2 definitions for the same abstract object. So i wanna ask what was the motive to define a lie algebra or more abstract an algebra, what is the use, how and why it is helpful?

(I am an undergraduate with no experience on courses who study the above, just curious trying to understand it on my own)

Comment: I do not really find it very similar. One is a bilinear form $V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$, with symmetry and positivity conditions, and the other is an internal bilinear product $V\times V\to V$ with antisymmetry and other algebraic conditions.

Comment: The cross product is more similar ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also do not find them particularly similar.

The motivation to define Lie algebras is simply that rings of square matrices are really important, the commutator of matrices is also very important, the general identity that matrix commutators obey is the Jacobi identity, so it makes sense to abstract that away and consider what other algebraic structures obey the Jacobi identity. They also arise naturally in the study of Lie groups as an in some sense simpler fragment of the group.

Inner products are simply abstractions of dot products, which arise very soon after you start working with 3D vectors.

"Algebra" is an overloaded term. It usually refers to an associative algebra over a field, but by no means always. In that sense, Lie algebras are not actually algebras, though associative algebras give rise to Lie algebras through the commutator.